# Node.JS AJAX empty body

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax

Can't get `data` on server side from AJAX-request because `req.body` is empty (console logs it's `{}`).
script.js:

```
$("#button").click(function(){
    var number = $("#number").val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "/multiply",
            type: "get",
            data: number,
            cache: false,
            success: function(data){
                $("#result").html(data);
            }
        });
});
```

server side:

```
app.get('/multiply', urlencodedParser, function(req, res, next){
    console.log(req.body); //logs {}
    res.send('ok');
});
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test AJAX</title>
</head>
<body>

    <input type="text" name="number" id="number">
    <button type="button" id="button">Multiply</button>

    <div id="result">

    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the number to the URL as a parameter:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/multiply?number=" + number,
    type: "get",
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {
        $("#result").html(data);
    }
});
```

And on the server side, you can get that value using the req.query object:

```
console.log(req.query.number);
```

Answer (score 0):

http get request has no request body. jQuery will convert data to url params automatically, so you need get that value in `req.query`.

Answer (score 0):

In your sever side to change `req.body` with `req.query.number` and in your `$.ajax` you can add the number as data property like this:

```
$("#button").click(function(){
var number = $("#number").val();
    $.ajax({
        url: "/multiply",
        type: "get",
        data: {number: number},
        cache: false,
        success: function(data){
            $("#result").html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

For POST request we use `req.body` and for GET request we use `req.query` for queryStrings.

- notice that `req.query.number` is a `string` because its GET request